# How to set up dev enviorument to not slow down whole computer?

Tags: windows-8, performance

I'm going to buy good PC with intel i7, 8GB ram and SSD HD. I'm PHP developer so I will install IIS, MySQL Workbench, PHP Engine, PHP Storm and other dev tools for my purposes. Simultaniously I'm a game player and just ordinary web user who likes when all the programs works fast. I want to have all the tools I need and be able to create programs fast and use programs like MS Word, Firefox, Photoshop without getting upset etc.

What should I do to achieve above goals? Should I set two operating systems? It's kinda inconvenient because I will have to reboot to switch from dev env to entertaiment dev. I use Windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Installing software does not slow a computer down.  Running software  consumes resources, but it appears that IIS is the only thing in the list that would run as a service.  If you stop IIS when you aren't using it, this should be sufficient.

Comment: MySQL and some others too... I don't want to stop them all everytime I want to play game and then lanuch them again after all.

Comment: Get more RAM. It will be worth it.

Comment: @PAM You can write a batch script that would stop and start services in one hit.  Surely this is more convenient and quicker than dual booting or using a VM?

Answer (score 1):

you could run the servers (IIS, mysql, etc..) in a virtual machine and stop it when not needed.

Comment: I'm considering this. I'm afraid that working in a wirtual machine will be slow.

Comment: it is not slow, mainly if you run only the servers on it (most of the servers today run in virtual machines anyway). Your servers will have low demand as they are used only by you. You could even consider running your entire development in a vm I think, so if something goes wrong with the game part, the dev part is secure.